# "Soft" restart an app after settings change

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Is there an easy way to relaunch my application from the starting window like it was freshly launched (show the splash screen and rebind all of my initial data)?

The reason being is that we have a line of business app that basically talks to different endpoints. If the endpoint changes in the settings, I want to show a dialog box when the settings pane closes that will ask to relaunch the app to get information for the newly selected endpoint.

If not, I can always have the application navigate back to the root frame of the application and rebind all of my data. Just was curious if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can force your app to restart so your best option seems to be to clean up all your state yourself and navigate back to the beginning. Perhaps also wrap any code you put in the `App` class' to handle app initialization events and call it again after you've cleaned things up.